# set builder mathematical notation in clustering algorithm

Tags: notation

I came across a clustering algorithm, which uses the set builder notation to specify the clusters (or elements in the cluster). The algorithm is [here](https://openaccess.thecvf.com/content_cvpr_2018/papers/Ikami_Local_and_Global_CVPR_2018_paper.pdf).

The following is copied directly from the source, where the optimization function is this:

$$\mathit{E}(\mathbf{Z}) = \sum_{j=1}^k \frac{\mathbf{z}^⊤_j \mathbf{Az}_j}{f_j(\mathbf{Z})}$$

where:

$\mathbf{A} \in \mathbb{R}^{n×n}$ is the affinity matrix of *n* data points

$\mathbf{Z} = [\mathbf{z_1},···,\mathbf{z_k}] \in \mathcal{Z}, \mathcal{Z} = \{\mathbf{Z} \in \{0, 1\}^{n×k} | \mathbf{Z1} = \mathbf{1}\}$ is an assignment matrix, in which *k* is the number of clusters and **1** is the all-one vector

The optimization function and the affinity matrix $\mathbf{A}$ are logical, however, when you come to the notation of the clusters **Z** is where the problem lies. I'm not sure what the following notations mean:

1. The equation for $\mathcal{Z}$ is based on the predicate $\mathbf{Z1} = \mathbf{1}$, what does that mean? And why do the clusters $\mathbf{Z}$ belong to $\mathcal{Z}$ while $\mathcal{Z}$ is constructed by $\mathbf{Z}$ that belong to the $\{0, 1\}^{n×k}$ set?
2. The "all-one" vector is what? Presumably a row or column vectors of all 1s?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\mathbf{Z}$ is an $n \times k$ matrix, and the first $\mathbf{1}$ is a $k \times 1$ matrix (column vector) of 1s (often written as $\mathbf{e}$).  The second $\mathbf{1}$ is an $n \times 1$ matrix (column vector) of 1s, and $\mathbf{Z 1} = \mathbf{1}$ means $$\sum_{j=1}^k Z_{i,j} = 1$$ for $i \in \{1,\dots,n\}$.  Because $Z_{i,j} \in \{0,1\}$, this implies that each row $i$ contains exactly one 1 and exactly $k-1$ 0s.

Comment: Hmm I see, if $\mathbf{Z}$ is a $n \times k$ matrix, then are all components of $\mathbf{Z}$ i.e. $\mathbf{z_1},···,\mathbf{z_k}$ $n \times 1$ matrices? So $\mathbf{z_1}$ is $n \times 1$?

Comment: Yes, those are $n\times 1$.